# Visual Studio Not Working When Add Table in RDLC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, rdlc

Am using VS-2013. Already I add many RDLC reports inside my ERP project. But after update my SQL Server from 2008 to 2016, I can't add any table inside new or existing RDLC reports file or update DataSet. When I trying to do those that time my VS'13 stop working and restart it automatically. But previous adding RDLC reports are still working..
Already I search many site but can't get any right answer. Can anyone give me solution to overcome from this situation....

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem but i managed to solve it.

Solution:

1) I copy table from other rdlc, then paste it to new rdlc

2) To add dataset, i open rldc with Automatic Editor Selector (XML). Add dataset manually using xml script

This is not good or accurate solution but it does solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update the system and product.
this will add missing driver/files for MS SQL Server 2016.

Visual studio not working is an common problem when working with RDLC most of my coworker were facing this problem so i worked on this that why Visual Studio stop working/ crash. So i checked the log files in temp files and prefetch files and then i saw what is the actual problem like most of the time other DLL file was issue so i removed some unused DLL or added the requiered DLL. This method solved most of the visual studio working problum and in some other case the solution was different.

if you are facing this issue then tell me what is log file saying in error i think i can help. And the method above will help you